# Where does rails source file locate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys
I'm new to rails, I read something about reading source code is good way to study rails, and I found the related rb file in rails' online document, such as [this page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration_rb.html)
But I can't find where the rails source file locate in my mac, could someone to help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way is to look online at the [github repo](https://github.com/rails/rails/)

If you want to browse it locally, you can (depending on your version of rails) to a `bundle show rails` for Rails 3.0, this will tell you where it's installed.

For rails 2.3.x you just need to find out where the gem is installed and open that up.  If you're using RVM for instance it will be somewhere in ~/.rvm

Comment: You could also just clone the Github repository instead of digging up the installed gem version.